# When calculating to report backgroundworker progressBar i'm getting exception cant divide by zero what is wrong?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method:
Getting the Length of the files give 0 already.

```
public void DownloadFtpContent(object sender ,string file, string filesdirectories,string fn)
        {                       
            try
            {
                BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
                string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string ftpdirectories = Path.Combine(ftpcontentdir, filesdirectories);
                string fileurl = "ftp://" + file;
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fileurl);                                
                reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;                
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;                                
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;                 
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                if (!Directory.Exists(ftpdirectories))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(ftpdirectories);
                }
                FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly, FileMode.Create);
                string fnn = ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly;
                int Length = 2048;
                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
                int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                long FileSize = new FileInfo(fnn).Length;
                string FileSizeDescription = GetFileSize(FileSize);
                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
                    string SummaryText = String.Format("Transferred {0} / {1}", GetFileSize(bytesRead), FileSizeDescription);
                    bw.ReportProgress((int)(((decimal)bytesRead / (decimal)FileSize) * 100), SummaryText);
                }                
                writeStream.Close();
                response.Close(); 
            }
            catch (WebException wEx)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
            }
        }
    }
```

Already on this line the result is 0:

```
long FileSize = new FileInfo(fnn).Length;
```

In fnn i have: c:\myftpdownloads\root\Images\CB 967x330.jpg
Why the result of the Length is 0 ?

And the file is not 0kb size.

EDIT

This is how i'm calling the download method from backgroundworker dowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                int fn = numberOfFiles[i].IndexOf(txtHost.Text, 0);
                string fn1 = numberOfFiles[i].Substring(txtHost.Text.Length + 1, numberOfFiles[i].Length - (txtHost.Text.Length + 1));
                string dirs = Path.GetDirectoryName(fn1);
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(fn1);
                ftpProgress1.DownloadFtpContent(sender,numberOfFiles[i], dirs, filename);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use the debugger, Luke!

Comment: I see now using breakpoint that the file in this position still not yet downloaded on my hard disk the file on the hard disk is 0 bytes size. And i don't see the image it self. But without calculating and reporting to progress the files were downloading fine. So how and where should i make the calculation ? Maybe somewhere inside the while ? Or after the file was downloaded and if it was downloaded ok ? In uploading i don't have a problem since the file is from theh ard disk so the size is known and easy to get. But downloading i guess i don't know the filze size if it wasnt downloaded yet.

Answer (score 2):

```
In fnn i have: c:\myftpdownloads\root\Images\CB 967x330.jpg Why the result of the Length is 0 ?
```

It doesn't really matter why the result of the length is 0. It does matter that you divide that number by 0 without any protection.

Just check before you divide:

```
if( FileSize != 0 ){...}
```

Comment: I added to my question the dowork event of the backgroundworker in form1 of how i'm calling the download method. The problem Grant is right that i'm sending one file and i think since the file didn't download yet and it will keep moving to the next file. So even using this protection check it's all the time 0.